# Azure pipeline Multi Stage set build Number as part of the stage name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, slack

I am working on a multi stage pipeline that build and deploy some c# code from `staging` to `production`

Everything works just fine but I wanted to try and customise a bit more the pipeline so I can see the actual version that is being built and deployed as part of the name of the stage.

At the current stage, this my multi stage pipeline

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  tags:
    include:
      - '*'
  branches:
    exclude:
      - main
      - staging

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
variables:
  buildNumber: "$[variables['Build.BuildNumber']]"
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
  dockerRegistryServiceConnectionStaging: '<My-Connection-String>'
  imageRepositoryStaging: '<My-Repo-Name>'
  containerRegistryStaging: '<My-Container-Name>'

  dockerRegistryServiceConnectionProd: '<My-Connection-String>'
  imageRepositoryProd: 'My-Repo-Name>'
  containerRegistryProd: '<My-Container-Name>'
  dockerfilePath: 'pathTo/Dockerfile'
  solution: 'path/To/Solution.csproj'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'

stages:
- stage: 'Build_Staging'
  displayName: 'Build_Staging'
  jobs:
  - job: buildStaging
    displayName: 'DotNet Core publish and dockerize'

    steps:
    - powershell: |
        # Write your PowerShell commands here.
        
        Write-Host "Update Build.BuildNumber"
        cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        $Latesttag = $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
        Write-Host "The latest git tag is $Latesttag "
        Write-Host
        "##vso[build.updatebuildNumber]$Latesttag"
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'DotNet - Restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: $(solution)
        noCache: true
        versioningScheme: 'off'
        vstsFeed: '<Feed>'

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      name: 'DotnetPublish'
      displayName: 'dotnet - Publish'
      inputs:
        command: 'publish'
        projects: $(solution)
        arguments: '-o publish/solution -c release'
        modifyOutputPath: false
        zipAfterPublish: false
        publishWebProjects: false
        
    - task: Docker@2
      name: 'dockerBuildAndPush'
      displayName: 'docker - Build & Push $(tag)'
      inputs:
        repository: $(imageRepositoryStaging)
        Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: ${{ variables.dockerRegistryServiceConnectionStaging }}
        buildContext: ${{ variables.buildContext }}
        tags: |
          $(Build.BuildNumber)
          latest
          
- stage: 'Deploy_Staging'
  jobs: 
  - deployment: 'Deploy'
    environment: 'Staging'
    variables:
      EnvironmentName: 'Staging'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:     
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service To Staging'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '<Azure-Subscription>'
              appType: 'webAppContainer'
              DockerNamespace: '<container-namespace>'
              DockerRepository: '<Repository>'
              DockerImageTag: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
              WebAppName: '<WebAppName>'
```

The Powershell command is to override the `Build.BuildNumber` with the tag I am pushing to GitHub.

When I run this pipeline, in azure DevOps, I see the stage name `Build_Staging_$(Build.BuildNumber)` as a string.

What I would really like to see is, if I push the tag 'v1.0.0` for example, is to see the stage name like:

```
Build_Staging_v1.0.0
```

I tried to use the displayName and the output is not the one I was looking for and if I try with `name` instead of `displayName` I get the error `unexpected value name`

Can please please anyone help understand what am I doing wrong and how I can achieve this?

Please if my question is not 100% clear and missing any important detail, just let me know

UPDATE:

I did update the post with my entire pipeline.
This pipeline, before it used to be a single job process, and everything was working fine. But to get my hand dirty, I wanted to add stages to split and workflow based on resources and environment.

The process is still working and this is what I am expecting.

In my GitHub, when I create a tag on the main branch, this will trigger my build stage. Which thanks to the Powershell script to update the BuildNumber with the tag, I am able to build the docker image in my container registry in the following format:

```
docker-image-name:v1.0.1
```

That version can be seen at this level also:

[image]

This updated buildNumber (now is Tag) is use in `Azure pipelines App Slack` to check the version that has been pushed.

So far everything is good.

But I am facing the problem with the `deployment job`, at that level I am not able to set any Powershell script to update that same BuildNumber with the tag. I checked the documentation and nothing is mentioned about how I can add another job or step. I tried implementing this but I get errors that the value is unexpected.

Let me just share another screenshot to fully explain the issue.

Assuming I am deploying the docker image v1.0.1, everything works perfectly, but the build number in deployment stage, is not being updated, in fact in slack channel, I see the normal build number, as follow:

[image]

Instead of having the buildNumber, I would like to have my tag.

Please any help here?

Comment: Following up on your update. Your initial post was asking for instructions on how to update the STAGE NAME with the variable. Are you now looking for how to update the PIPELINE NAME?

Comment: Hi, the 2 issues are related. Because in both cases I am not able to update the stage  buildNumber. As default is always coming the azure DevOps buildNumber based on the date and the release. I thought that the issue is related to both scenario, but if is not I can open a different post for that

Comment: Unfortunately, the pipeline name itself can only use the Azure DevOps Predefined variables. So, you're correct, it's related to the same issue you're encountering with the stage name. You can't do what you're trying to accomplish unless you have a separate process that updates a variable group value bound in your pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to set a stage name to a dynamic variable that is set within one of its child's steps. You'll have to set it to a **pipeline-level variable** or **predefined variable**

Variable evaluation goes top-down from stages to tasks:

- stages

  - jobs

    - tasks

---

To help explain exactly why, let's talk about how variable evaluation works in general with regard to this structure:

- **VARIABLE EVALUATION:** Using stages as an example, you can set a **stage** name using any dynamic value that's present when the stage **is evaluated**. This means the variable is only accessed when the stage is initially "rendered". Azure DevOps requires that the variable be present before evaluation and will not retroactively update the UI if that variable is changed within a child step.

Let's talk about each and their respective limitations on what variables you can use in their **names**:

- **STAGES:** pipeline-level variables, parameters (in the case of templates), or [**predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- **JOBS:** stage-level variables, pipeline-level variables, parameters (in the case of templates), or [**predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- **TASKS:** job-level variables, stage-level variables, pipeline-level variables, parameters (in the case of templates), or [**predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and help. So if I understand correctly. If I set a variable that point to the tag of github master branch, I should be able to use that for the stage as it will be a predifined variable?

Comment: Or if you can advice me with any best practice to achieve this I would be grateful

Comment: That might work. The stage name will be set to the initial value of your custom pipeline-level variable. However, any updates after its initial value will not be reflected in the stage name. I describe a bit more about how this functions in "VARIABLE EVALUATION"

Answer (score -1):

I did something similar by setting my build number to a repo tag.  Here is the PowerShell function that sets the Build.Buildnumber variable to the tag value.  You can just call it straight out or base it off a parameter if you have other version number logic.

```
   function getTagVersion() {
      $tag = iex "git describe --long --tags --always"
      $a = [regex]"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+"
      $b = $a.Match($tag)
      $b = $b.Captures[0].value
      $b = $b -replace '-', '.'
      $b = $b -replace 'v', ''
      Write-Host "Version found: $b"
      $newBuildNumber = '$(Build.BuildNumber)' -replace $a,$b
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$newBuildNumber"
      return $b
   }
```

I can't claim credit for this code as I found it on someone's blog.  But it works and I use for my release builds.  You just have to call the function and it will reset the build.buildnumber to the latest tag in your repo.  Its important to note, that the tag should be in normal version number format.

Example:
Tag Name: 10.1.100.0

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you so much for your reply. Is there any difference between your code and my powershell task? Because in my case, with that script, it does update the build number in the pipeline name, not at the tasks level.

Comment: This won't work. The stage name won't be updated after you set a new build number. Instead, the stage name will be evaluated as the initial value of $(Build.BuildNumber)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience. I did try to set the Powershell script in my `Deploy_STaging` stage, but that did not update the stage build number. It was always showing the default format and not the tag

Comment: Your original post before you edited it asked about updating the build.buildnumber to a tag.  The code I posted above will do that and if you were to correct the build number with a task before you set your staging, this would work.  But you changed your problem description to be something completely different.  Good luck.